# How to encode a column to the same type

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, type-conversion, dummy-variable

I want to ceate a dummy variable so I creaed the following command:
`dummyset$Jakr <- ifelse(dummyset$Landkreis == "Jagstkreis", 1, 0)`
Everything works but I have a few rows where Landkreis == Jagstkreis and still there is no 1 appearing in the dummycolumn.
I tried removing blank spaces and all stuff and came to the point where I saw the encoding of one row is "unknown" whereas the other wa "UTF-8".
The thing is the command works on every row that is "unkown" but on no where it is "UTF-8".
Next I tried:
`dummyset$Landkreis <- iconv(dummyset$Landkreis, from = "UTF-8", to = "unknown") dummyset$Landkreis <- stri_enc_toutf8(dummyset$Landkreis) dummyset$Landkreis <- gsub("[^[:print:]]", "", dummyset$Landkreis)`

But no matter what i try the encoding wont change...

Does anyone has a idea on how to approach this problem?
Thanks!

I tried to convert two rows into the same encoding as a command was only working on one row but not on the other

Comment: try `dummyset$Landkreis <- enc2native(dummyset$Landkreis)`